# Can I download a video partially from the internet?

Tags: video, download

Is it possible to download only starting few MBs of video? I need to download a video which is more than 30MB. i just need to get a preview so that I can decide i really need to download that video or not..

Comment: What type of video (file type)? Can't you watch the start of it in your browser?

Comment: What operating system, for starters ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it most of the time. Find where the video is being downloaded, maybe browser cache or the folder where the video is being downloaded. The actual file is the one whose size is growing, maybe the name has attached a `.part` extension. A good media player should be able to play that file(if the extension is `.part` you have to associate it with the player).

In my case I download the videos with Firefox and play them with VLC from the destination folder where Firefox is placing them.

Answer (score 1):

For an addition to @mariom 's reply;

after you find the dowloading file (where in a cache folder),
you should do this if you could not open the downloading file :

**Step 1:** copy the file
**Step 2:** and paste to somewhere
(just select the file and type ctrl+c and ctrl+v)
**Step 3:** and try to open that copied file in a media player.
if you cannot open the copied file, please inform me and I can help.
You should also try to change the file type of the copied file and then you can open (after making visible the file types in explorer).

You can do these steps for most of the files that are downloading and can use any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the video is set up a streaming video and your browser has the appropriate plug-ins to view that video stream.  If the video is stored/linked to as a file download (i.e. as a zip file for example, or just linked to on a web page that is not set up to stream the video), then no, you cannot download just a small part and watch just the first bit.